# Calculating a global Proj

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How would one identify $\textbf{Proj}(\mathcal{O}\oplus \mathcal{O}(1)^{\oplus 2} \oplus \cdots)$ with $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^2$?

In general I've been having a hard time going from the global proj of some quasi coherent sheaf to describing an actual space. Any insightful example calculations in this direction would also be appreciated.

Comment: What are these twisting sheaves living on? What is the ring structure on this sheaf?

Comment: I believe they are on ${\mathbb{P}^1}$